# How to append values from an hash to another one using Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap

I have a hash:

```
{:userdata=>["field: email,start: 0,end: 0"]}
```

and I want to add to another hash that looks like this:

```
{:userdata=>["field: resource.attributes.account_source.iban,start: 0,end: 0", "field: resource.attributes.account_source.person_name,start: 0,end: 0", "field: resource.attributes.account_target.iban,start: 0,end: 0", "field: resource.attributes.account_target.person_name,start: 0,end: 0"], :iddata=>["field: resource.attributes.account_source.account_id,start: 0,end: 0", "field: resource.attributes.account_source.person_id,start: 0,end: 0", "field: resource.attributes.account_target.account_id,start: 0,end: 0", "field: resource.attributes.account_target.person_id,start: 0,end: 0"], :infodata=>["field: resource.attributes.reason,start: 0,end: 0"], :balancedata=>["field: resource.attributes.amount,start: 0,end: 0"]}
```

There are multiple keys in the second hash and array of values, so I need to add the value in the correct place, which should be something like:

```
 {:userdata=>["field: resource.attributes.account_source.iban,start: 0,end: 0", "field: resource.attributes.account_source.person_name,start: 0,end: 0", "field: resource.attributes.account_target.iban,start: 0,end: 0", "field: resource.attributes.account_target.person_name,start: 0,end: 0", "field: email,start: 0,end: 0"], ....
```

The second hash is more complex, that may contain the same key of the hash that I'm trying to "merge" but of course is missing the value, which is what I want to add in the second hash.

Comment: In Ruby we call them a Hash. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and their linked pages. We'd like to see your attempt to solve this. Without that it looks like you want us to write code for you, which isn't what SO is for. As written your question is too broad.

Comment: I know it is a Hash, are you referring the mistake on the title? I can change it , i didn't write the question because i wanted code, i wrote because i was not understanding how to solve my problem, that is different.

Comment: I'd like to thank you for the link you sent me, that was helpful because I verified that the information I wrote helped people identify the problem because I explained that using 2 hash map, you cannot merge them in this case because the output is still the second hash. In fact, I said that when I tried to merge, it was still missing the values. It is also **Verifiable** because I Described the problem, **Eliminated any issues that were not relevant to the problem**, in fact, I didn't mention the other problems I was having with creating the correct strings inside the arrays.

Comment: While you attempted to justify why you wrote the question the way you did, it remains that it isn't written how it should be for SO. "[mcve]" repeatedly says code is needed to demonstrate the problem you're having. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)" helps explain it from the standpoint of the rest of the community. See also "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" and "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) with a block, and use [`Array#|`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-7C) to get the union of two arrays:

```
h1 = { userdata: ['field: email,start: 0,end: 0'] }
h2 = { userdata: ['field: resource.attributes.account_source.iban,start: 0,end: 0', 'field: resource.attributes.account_source.person_name,start: 0,end: 0', 'field: resource.attributes.account_target.iban,start: 0,end: 0', 'field: resource.attributes.account_target.person_name,start: 0,end: 0'], iddata: ['field: resource.attributes.account_source.account_id,start: 0,end: 0', 'field: resource.attributes.account_source.person_id,start: 0,end: 0', 'field: resource.attributes.account_target.account_id,start: 0,end: 0', 'field: resource.attributes.account_target.person_id,start: 0,end: 0'], infodata: ['field: resource.attributes.reason,start: 0,end: 0'], balancedata: ['field: resource.attributes.amount,start: 0,end: 0'] }

h3 = h1.merge(h2) { |_, old_array, new_array| new_array | old_array | }
# {:userdata=>["field: resource.attributes.account_source.iban,start: 0,end: 0", "field: resource.attributes.account_source.person_name,start: 0,end: 0", "field: resource.attributes.account_target.iban,start: 0,end: 0", "field: resource.attributes.account_target.person_name,start: 0,end: 0", "field: email,start: 0,end: 0"], :iddata=>["field: resource.attributes.account_source.account_id,start: 0,end: 0", "field: resource.attributes.account_source.person_id,start: 0,end: 0", "field: resource.attributes.account_target.account_id,start: 0,end: 0", "field: resource.attributes.account_target.person_id,start: 0,end: 0"], :infodata=>["field: resource.attributes.reason,start: 0,end: 0"], :balancedata=>["field: resource.attributes.amount,start: 0,end: 0"]}
```

Note that `:userdata` and `'userdata'` aren't the same Ruby objects and aren't considered to be the same key in a Hash.

Finally, the values in your hash aren't hashes but string arrays. Two strings with the same field but different values will be considered completely distinct :

```
['field: a'] | ['field: a, value: 1']
# ["field: a", "field: a, value: 1"]
```

If you want the functionality of a hash, use a [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html).

Comment: thanks a lot! so it's basically the array method of joining two arrays... wow!